# Checking registry value changes via modbus tcp

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, modbus, modbus-tcp

I use the EasyModbus library to connect the computer with the microcontroller.

Problem:
I need to read global registers / variables on the microcontroller via ModbusTCP <> it is not a single reading, it must check the state whether the given register has changed and assign its value to the variable / field (close to real time)

I tried :
In any method I can read the registers via ReadHoldingRegisters, the class itself doesn't have this option anymore.

```
public static ModbusClient modbusClient = new ModbusClient();

void sth
{
 int[] registers = modbusClient.ReadHoldingRegisters(2500, 5);
}
```

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this / can someone direct me?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to poll the microcontroller, Modbus does not have support for events or similar features.

Comment: How can I poll the microcontroller?

Comment: I do not know the library you are using, you have to find how to send Modbus requests to the server. Maybe this page helps? http://easymodbustcp.net/en/modbusclient-methods

Comment: I use EasyModbus library